# Separate Date and time with " (String.Format)

Tags: c#, datetime, string.format

Is it possible to separate Date and time with ".

So it would be:

```
"ddMMyyyy","HHmmss"
```

Right now i have:

```
DateTime dt = aPacket.dtTimestamp;
string d = dt.ToString("\"ddMMyyyy\",\"HHmmss\"");
```

and String.Format shows me just ["ddMMyyyy,HHmmss"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr9nm.png)

Thank you everyone for helping me !!! But i will mark the first answer as the right one

Comment: What you ware expected

Comment: @un-lucky i know that " \"ddMMyyyy\",\"HHmmss\" " and that [ \" ] does nothing , this is why i ask here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try *formatting*:

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
 // "01072016","101511"
 string d = String.Format("\"{0:ddMMyyyy}\",\"{0:HHmmss}\"", dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

`"` is a formatting character, so it needs to be escaped with `\`, e.g.

```
string d = dt.ToString("\\\"ddMMyyyy\\\",\\\"HHmmss\\\"");
```

You may find a verbatim string slightly more readable:

```
string d = dt.ToString(@"\""ddMMyyyy\"",\""HHmmss\""");
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would say like this:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var date = now.ToString("ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var time = now.ToString("HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dt = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "\"{0}\",\"{1}\"", date, time);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Comment: Probably would have been wicked if you stored the result of padding it with `"` and `,` into a variable rather than doing it time via `Console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var formattedDateTime = $"{now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")},{now.ToString("HHmmss")}";
```